# time stamp in log file

Tags: logging, autosys

i have to create a autosys job to monitor another autosys long running job.  the monitoring job should create an alert if the other job is running for more than 10 minutes.

for ex. A1 autosys job will run and create a log file. The new monitoring job should check the log file time stamp created date and time and check the log file is running for more than 10 minutes.
if the log file created within 1o minutes then it is ok else create an alert.

Could you plese suggest if there any commond to find this.

Thanks in advance
os linux red hat

Comment: what command you need ? to check  file timestamp or to run an alert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find if directory contain a file that was modified more than 10 minutes ago use

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -mmin +10 -printf "found" |grep -q found
if [[ $? == 0 ]];then do_alert;fi
```

Comment: it worked thanks.sorry i didt inform this earlier. but the Main Job in this case A1 will run every   1 hour of interval and append the same log file. in that case the above given solution alert immediately. is there a  command to compare based on the time stamp. please advice

Comment: not sure what you mean, you want to delete files which older than some selected time ? like you save date to the file with `date +%s` ?

Comment: easy way is to keep timestamp in temporary file, touch it and use 
`find /path/to/dir/ -type f -not -newer /path/to/timestampfile -printf "found" |grep -q found
if [[ $? == 0 ]];then do_alert;fi`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MAXRUN` setting in the `JIL` (the job definition)

```
max_run_alarm: 10
```

There is no need to create another job to monitor for this.